# Density of Lipschitz functions with compact support

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions, approximation-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a locally compact metric space. Consider the space of complex continuous functions $C_0(X)$ which vanish at infinity.

I am interested in the following fact:

*The space of **compactly supported** Lipschitz functions $Lip_{c,d}(X)$ is uniformly dense in $C_0(X)$*.

I know that $Lip_d(X)$ is uniformly dense in $C_0(X)$, and that $C_c(X)$ is uniformly dense in $C_0(X)$.

1. But how can one prove that $Lip_{c,d}(X)$ is uniformly dense in $C_c(X)$?
2. Is there any reference for the above fact?

Many thanks!

Comment: This follows directly from the triangular inequality. First approximate $f \in C_0(X)$ by a function $g \in C_c(X)$ and then approximate $g$ by a Lipschitz continuous function on the support of $g$.

Comment: @Klaus, Hi! And what would be a Lipschitz continuous function on the support of $g$? We may have that the Lipschitz function which unif. approx. $g$ has no compact support and just vanishes at infinity.

Comment: In the second step you use the result on $Y = \mathrm{supp}(g)$ (as opposed to $X$), so that the approximation to g will also have support in $Y$.