# Functions with compact supports: if $X$ is locally compact then $\operatorname{Lip}_c (X)$ is dense in $\mathcal C_c(X)$

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to prove a result in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773346/density-of-lipschitz-functions-with-compact-support) thread.

> **Theorem** Let $(X, d)$ be a locally compact metric space, Then the space $\operatorname{Lip}_c (X)$ of Lipschitz continuous functions with **compact supports** is dense in the space $\mathcal C_c(X)$ of continuous functions with **compact supports**.

Could you check if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $f:X \to \mathbb R$ be continuous with compact support. Let's construct a Lipschitz continuous function $\bar f:X \to \mathbb R$ with compact support such that $\|f-\bar f\|_\infty < 2\varepsilon$. We need the following lemmas.

- [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914363/open-sets-with-compact-closure-containing-a-given-compact-set) Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological space. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ and $U$ an open subset of $X$ such that $K \subset U$. Then there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $K \subset V \subset \overline V \subset U$ and $\overline V$ is compact.
- [Lemma 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448404/the-space-of-lipschitz-continuous-functions-is-dense-in-that-of-uniformly-contin?rq=1) The space $\operatorname{Lip}_b (X)$ of bounded Lipschitz continuous functions is dense in the space $\mathcal C_b(X)$ of bounded continuous functions w.r.t. the supremum norm.

Let $K := \operatorname{supp} f$. By **Lemma 1**, there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $K \subset V$ and $\overline V$ is compact. By **Lemma 2**, There is a bounded Lipschitz continuous function $h:V \to \mathbb R$ such that $\sup_{x \in V} |f(x)-h(x)| < \varepsilon$. This implies $\sup_{x \in V \setminus K} |h(x)| < \varepsilon$.

By [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma#Formal_Statement), there is a [Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619187/urysohn-function-is-lipschitz-of-at-least-one-of-the-closed-sets-is-compact) continuous $g:X \to [0, 1]$ such that $g(K)=1$ and $g(X \setminus V) = 0$. We define $\bar f$ by $\bar f (x) := h(x) g(x)$ for all $x \in V$ and $0$ otherwise. The product of two Lipschitz functions [is again Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028974/sum-and-product-of-lipschitz-functions), so $\bar f$ is Lipschitz. Clearly, $\operatorname{supp} \bar f \subset \overline V$ and thus $\operatorname{supp} \bar f$ is compact. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\|f-\bar f\|_\infty &=\sup_{x \in V} |f(x)-\bar f(x)| \\
&\le  \sup_{x \in V} |f(x)-h(x)| + \sup_{x \in V} |\bar f(x)-h(x)| \\
&\le \varepsilon +\sup_{x \in V} |\bar f(x)-h(x)|.
\end{align}
$$

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sup_{x \in V} |\bar f(x)-h(x)| &=\sup_{x \in V \setminus K} |\bar f(x)-h(x)| \\
&= \sup_{x \in V \setminus K} |h(x)| \cdot |g(x)-1|  \\
&\le \sup_{x \in V \setminus K} |h(x)|  < \varepsilon. \\
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $\|f-\bar f\|_\infty \le 2 \varepsilon$. This completes the proof.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I'm aware of your linked question, but mine is about functions with compact supports.

Comment: I double-checked the proof, and only the proof, not the lemmas, looks fine to me. Also, no possible improvements or reasonable alternatives come to mind.

Comment: @Matija Thank you so much for your verification! Luckily, the two lemmas are well-known.