# Urysohn function is Lipschitz if at least one of the closed sets is compact

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. For a subset $A$ of $X$, let $d_A(x) := \inf_{a \in A} d(x, a)$. Let $x,y \in X$. For $b \in A$, we have
$$
d_A(x) -d(y, b)  = \inf_{a \in A} (d(x, a) - d(y, b)) \le d(x,b)-d(y,b) \le d(x,y).
$$

So $d_A(x) -d_A(y) \le d(x,y)$. By symmetry, $|d_A(x) -d_A(y)| \le d(x,y)$ and thus the map $x \mapsto d_A(x)$ is $1$-Lipschitz. In proving this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619138/if-x-d-is-locally-compact-then-operatornamelip-c-x-is-dense-in-ma#4619138), I have come across below theorem, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $A,B$ be two closed subsets of $X$ such that $A$ is **compact** and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Then the map $f:X \to \mathbb R$ defined by
> $$
> f(x) := \frac{d_A(x)}{d_A(x)+d_B(x)} \quad \forall x\in X.
> $$
> is Lipschitz such that $f(A)=1$ and $f(B)=0$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** It's clear that $f(A)=1$ and $f(B)=0$.  Notice that $d_A(x)+d_B(x) \ge d(A,B) := \inf\{d(a,b) : a\in A, b\in B\}>0$ because $A$ is compact, $B$ is closed, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Fix $x,y\in X$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)| &= \left | \frac{d_A(x)}{d_A(x)+d_B(x)}  - \frac{d_A(y)}{d_A(y)+d_B(y)} \right | \\
&= \frac{|d_A(x) d_B(y) - d_A(y) d_B(x)|}{[d_A(x)+d_B(x)][d_A(y)+d_B(y)]} \\
&= \frac{|d_A(x) [d_B(y)-d_B(x)] + d_B(x) [d_A(x)-d_A(y)]|}{[d_A(x)+d_B(x)][d_A(y)+d_B(y)]} \\
&\le \frac{d_A(x) |d_B(y)-d_B(x)| }{[d_A(x)+d_B(x)][d_A(y)+d_B(y)]} + \frac{d_B(x) | d_A(x)-d_A(y)|}{[d_A(x)+d_B(x)][d_A(y)+d_B(y)]} \\
&\le \frac{d_A(x) d(x,y) }{[d_A(x)+d_B(x)][d_A(y)+d_B(y)]} + \frac{d_B(x) d(x,y)}{[d_A(x)+d_B(x)][d_A(y)+d_B(y)]} \\
&\le \frac{d(x,y) }{d_A(y)+d_B(y)} + \frac{d(x,y)}{d_A(y)+d_B(y)} \\
&\le \frac{2d(x,y) }{d(A,B)} .
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what $f(A)$ is supposed to be, I guess it's just the image of $A$ under $f$. Anyway, can you please double-check that it's $f(A)=1$, $f(B)=0$ and not the other way around?

Comment: @Matija You are right! I meant by $f(A)$ the image of $A$ under $f$. Indeed, it should be $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$.

Comment: The proof is sound. Yes, we need (sequential) compactness to obtain the existence of a limit point in $A$ which is then a limit point to both, yielding a contradiction. I would just change the assertion to $A,B$ such that $d(A,B)>0$. That's intuitive, too, and closedness, compactness are only required to get the positive distance. Clearly, the altered result is significantly stronger, and the Theorem as stated in the question is then an immdiate corollary. But of course, that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Matija Thank you so much for your comment. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Urysohn function as such. If $f,g$ are Lipschitz, non negative and $f+g$ uniformly bounded away from zero, then ${f \over f+g}$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per request, I post the comment as an answer.

The proof is sound. Yes, we need (sequential) compactness to obtain the existence of a limit point in $A$,
which is then a limit point to both, yielding a contradiction. I would just change the assertion to $A,B$ such that $d(A,B)>0$. That's intuitive, too, and closedness, compactness are only required to get the positive distance. Clearly, the altered result is significantly stronger, and the Theorem as stated in the question is then an immdiate corollary. But of course, that's a matter of taste.

Comment: In chess we say "To win you must use all your pieces". The proposer saw the way to use the compactness of $A$ or $B$ by $0<\inf_{x\in X}d_A(x)+d_B(x). $